# How to use awk to group by process name and sum up the memory and cpu usage?

Tags: awk

I have an ps output file name ps which contain %cpu, %mem and process name like below

```
3.0     0.1     php-fpm: pool www
2.0     0.1     php-fpm: pool www
1.0     0.1     php-fpm: pool www
9.0     0.1     chrome
9.0     0.1     chrome
```

I want to sum up the cpu and memory usage of same process. so expected output will be

```
6.0     0.3     php-fpm: pool www
18.0    0.2     chrome
```

Currently I use `awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP="\t"}{arr[$3]+=$1 }END {for (i in arr) print arr[i], i}' ps` to sum up single column, so i can only get

```
6.0         php-fpm: pool www
18.0        chrome
```

How could i do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two arrays

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"}{a0[$3]+=$1; a1[$3]+=$2 }END {for (i in a0) print a0[i], a1[i], i}'
```